# Erro Xamarin.Forms Android - new HttpClient()

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, http, xamarin-forms

Aparece esse erro (imagem) sempre que chega nessa linha:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o código completo.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LivrosApp.ApiLivros
{
    public static class Api
    {
        public static async Task<IList<Model.Livro>> GetAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://mvalivros.azurewebsites.net/api/livros");
                var livros = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.Livro>>(json);
                return livros;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Já refiz a solução, já dei Clean na solução e nos projetos, fiz build, fiz rebuild, ativei todas as exceções... Nada funciona...

Marquei todas as funções abaixo também.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara, entra em Debug > Windows > Exceptions e me diz se a opção *Common Language Runtime Exceptions* está marcada com um tick (✓), um quadrado ou não está marcada

Comment: Oi.. esta tudo... coloquei na pergunta uma imagem.

Comment: Adiciona um try/cath para verificar o exception gerado. Outra coisa você está testado isto em uma VM Android? Verificou se tem internet nesta VM?